# Javascript calculation returning incorrect value

Tags: javascript, for

In my excel sheet I'm using this formula

```
=10615.30152 *(1+$B$9-$B$10)^L4
```

here $B$9= 2.75% and $B$10 = .20% and L4 changes for each row from 0 to 30

In my javascript I'm trying to calculate value like this:

```
for(let i=0;i<31; i++){
 cashFlow = 10615.30152 * (1 + 2.75/100 - 0.20/100) ** i;
}
```

With each new row the amount mismatching is getting bigger.

Comment: How do you figure? I tested this in a Google Spreadsheet and compared to the script (modified to show output at each step), and the calculations are accurate to five digits (JS outputs 12 digits after the decimal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I compared the output in a spreadsheet vs in JS, and come up with the following table:

| Index | Spreadsheet | JS Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10615.30152 | 10615.30152 |
| 1 | 10885.99171 | 10885.991708760002 |
| 2 | 11163.5845 | 11163.584497333384 |
| 3 | 11448.2559 | 11448.255902015384 |
| 4 | 11740.18643 | 11740.186427516777 |
| 5 | 12039.56118 | 12039.561181418458 |
| 6 | 12346.56999 | 12346.569991544628 |
| 7 | 12661.40753 | 12661.407526329016 |
| 8 | 12984.27342 | 12984.273418250408 |
| 9 | 13315.37239 | 13315.372390415794 |
| 10 | 13654.91439 | 13654.9143863714 |
| 11 | 14003.1147 | 14003.114703223871 |
| 12 | 14360.19413 | 14360.19412815608 |
| 13 | 14726.37908 | 14726.379078424063 |
| 14 | 15101.90174 | 15101.901744923878 |
| 15 | 15487.00024 | 15487.000239419434 |
| 16 | 15881.91875 | 15881.918745524632 |
| 17 | 16286.90767 | 16286.907673535512 |
| 18 | 16702.22382 | 16702.22381921067 |
| 19 | 17128.13053 | 17128.130526600544 |
| 20 | 17564.89786 | 17564.897855028856 |
| 21 | 18012.80275 | 18012.802750332095 |
| 22 | 18472.12922 | 18472.129220465562 |
| 23 | 18943.16852 | 18943.168515587437 |
| 24 | 19426.21931 | 19426.21931273492 |
| 25 | 19921.58791 | 19921.58790520966 |
| 26 | 20429.5884 | 20429.588396792507 |
| 27 | 20950.5429 | 20950.542900910717 |
| 28 | 21484.78174 | 21484.78174488394 |
| 29 | 22032.64368 | 22032.64367937849 |
| 30 | 22594.47609 | 22594.47609320264 |

I'm not sure what you're considering as descrepency, as the spreadsheet values are less accurate than the JS values by 7 digits past the decimal point, and all of them line up very closely to what the spreadsheet shows.

Perhaps you've made some error in your formula in the spreadsheet, or it may be a bug in Excel (I used Google Spreadsheets to perform this calculation).

Comment: apparently, my variable was returning 0